# firebase dependencies not working anymore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, npm, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Authentication in my Vuejs app and everything worked fine since today.
Now when I'm trying to start the app (npm run serve) I get the next error:

```
These dependencies were not found:

* firebase/app in ./src/helpers/firebase.js
* firebase/firebase-auth in ./src/helpers/firebase.js
* firebaseui in ./src/helpers/firebase.js
* firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css in ./src/main.js
```

I tried:

- deleting package-lock.json and node-modules folder and then reinstalling everything with "npm install";
- downloading an older version of my app, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that installing firebase again ("`npm install --save firebase`") worked today